# Kendo UI Dropdownlist Filter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using the latest Kendo UI version with jQuery version 1.8.

Everything works well except filtering in Kendo dropdownlists. When the filter is enabled, the dropdown is closed immediately after opening. Please see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/EaNm4/389/

**HTML**

```
<input id="dropdownlist" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#dropdownlist').kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: 'Select option...',
    dataTextField: 'text',
    dataValueField: 'value',
    dataSource: data,
    filter: "contains"
});
```

When I changed the jQuery to a higher version (>= 1.9), the problem was resolved. However for some reasons I can't upgrade jQuery version at the moment.
Does anyone know a "HACK" to fix this problem without changing jQuery version?
Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to get this yet? Have you tried removing the input and re-adding it by chance? I had this same issue and i was banging my head against the wall for hours. I completely removed the input and the .kendoDropDownList and tried going a different route wihout the kendo options.. then i decided to give it one more shot, and when i put a new select list on my page, then ran kendoDropDownList js again and it magically worked. Honestly i dont know what happened but that was the only variable. I did not change or update any javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
$("[data-role=dropdownlist]").each(function () {
    var widget = $(this).data("kendoDropDownList");

    widget.wrapper.on("keydown", function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

This is not my code, and unfortunately I cannot find the source, but as I understand it, the wrapper allows you to define some options not natively supported by the drop down list, like a keylistener, and "e.stopImmediatePropagation" in this case works similarly to "e.preventDefault", but only for the up-and-down action.  My issue was similar to yours, and this resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

That is only because od JS you can Change the JS Code  as of now it contains `aria-expanded="false"` but you have to Change like `aria-expanded="true"`. then it will work fine .it Defind Under :`class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header"`.
Click F12 and Check Console [image: Snapshot1]

[image: Snapshot2]

By Default it takes `aria-expanded="false"` but when i change it to `aria-expanded="true"` it works fine better see snapshot

Comment: Hi Anand,
Thanks for your answer.
I'm not sure I understand your comment correctly or not. I tried to change the aria-expanded="true", but it still does not work. Can you take a look on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EaNm4/395/

Comment: see my updated Comment and Snapshot . go to Debug Mode and Check which Span class is Using for Dropdown and change aria-expanded="false" to aria-expanded="true"

Comment: Hi Anand,
I followed your screenshots in different browsers (Chrome, IE, FireFox) but it still does not work.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites#what-to-do-when-an-older-jquery-version-is-required
Thanks.